# Maxima: trigonometric numbers in radical form

Tags: symbolic-math, maxima

Beginner's question for Maxima: how can I obtain [trigonometric numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_number) in radical form?

For example, this expression evaluates nicely:

```
(%i) cos( 3 * %pi / 4);
                                       1
(%o)                              - -------
                                    sqrt(2)
```

But this one does not:

```
(%i) cos(3 * %pi / 5);
                                     3 %pi
(%o)                             cos(-----)
                                       5
```

I would expect it to show something like this:

```
(%i) cos( 3 * %pi / 5);
                                  1 - sqrt(5)
(%o)                              -----------
                                       4
```

See, for example, the output from Wolfram Alpha:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%283+pi+%2F+5%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Maxima documentation for [`piargs`](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_10.html#IDX330),
which is `true` by default:

> When `%piargs` is `true`, trigonometric functions are simplified to algebraic
>   constants when the argument is an integer multiple of *%pi*, *%pi/2*,
>   *%pi/3*, *%pi/4*, or *%pi/6*.

From the Maxima documentation for [`ntrig`](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_10.html#IDX353):

> The `ntrig` package contains a set of simplification rules that are used to
>   simplify trigonometric function whose arguments are of the form
>   *`f`*`(`*`n`*`%pi/10)` where *f* is any of the functions `sin`, `cos`,
>   `tan`, `csc`, `sec` and `cot`.

This will work for 3π/5, but not for more complex values like π/96:

```
(%i) load(ntrig);
(%o)        /usr/share/maxima/5.34.1/share/trigonometry/ntrig.mac
(%i) cos(3*%pi/5);
                                 1 - sqrt(5)
(%o)                             -----------
                                      4
(%i) sin(4*%pi/10);
                             sqrt(sqrt(5) + 5)
(%o)                         -----------------
                                    3/2
                                   2
(%i) sin(%pi/96);
                                      %pi
(%o)                              sin(---)
                                      96
```

To evaluate more complex results,
the `trigeval` function from the `trigtools` package will work:

```
(%i) load(trigtools);
(%o)   /usr/share/maxima/5.34.1/share/contrib/trigtools/trigtools.mac
(%i) trigeval(sin(4*%pi/10));
                              sqrt(sqrt(5) + 5)
(%o)                          -----------------
                                     3/2
                                    2
(%i) trigeval(sin(%pi/96));
                   9/8                        3/2         5/4
             sqrt(2    - sqrt(sqrt(sqrt(3) + 2    + 1) + 2   ))
(%o)         --------------------------------------------------
                                    17/16
                                   2
```

There is some [documentation](https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/code/ci/master/tree/share/contrib/trigtools/trigtools-doc.pdf?format=raw)
for `trigtools`, but because it is part of the 3rd-party `contrib` packages,
it is not as well maintained.
The source code for `trigtools` [hasn't been updated since 2013](https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/code/ci/master/tree/share/contrib/trigtools/trigtools.mac).

Also, `trigeval` only seems to work for angles corresponding to regular polygons,
and not for trigonometric numbers in general.
For example, cos (π / 23) = -(1/2)(-1)<sup>22/23</sup>(1+(-1)<sup>2/23</sup>),
but `trigeval` is unhelpful in this case:

```
(%i) trigeval(cos(%pi/23));
                                      %pi
(%o)                              cos(---)
                                      23
```

Credit goes to [Serge de Marre](https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/mailman/message/35371080/)
and [Raymond Toy](https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/mailman/message/35371098/)
on the [maxima-discuss](https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/mailman/maxima-discuss/)
mailing list, as well as [David Billinghurst](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/160581/david-billinghurst)
on the [Maxima Area 51 Stackexchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102157/maxima/102928#102928).

Relevant links from other mailing lists:

- https://sourceforge.net/p/wxmaxima/discussion/435775/thread/f2340d15/#b66b/f24e/2708
- http://maxima-discuss.narkive.com/36FiqimH/trigtools-trigsolve-broken

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how cos(π/23) = -(1/2)(-1)^(22/23) * (1+(-1)^(2/23)) is useful to anyone.

You can express trig functions in terms of powers of -1, but then what?